# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET While accessing Firebase.com and all firebase apps

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, firebase

A few days ago I tried accessing a site: guides.emberjs.com
It is run on the firebase.com platform.
I was able to access this site before.
Now I get this error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Can't access any firebase sites/apps.
It happens across all browsers on my laptop.
When accessing the site by mobile phone on the same WiFi connection I can access the site.
I have done everything outlined [here](http://www.toppctech.com/err-connection-reset-fixed/).

Would love for some help.
Thanks

Comment: I can access `guides.emberjs.com` without problems. Stack Overflow is to help you with programming questions, while this seems a problem with the network connection on your laptop.

Comment: I thought I could also ask questions related to what I asked here. Can you recommend where I can ask for help?

Comment: This happens to mee too... The ONLY site I've found that has this error are the projects under firebase that I'm working on (https://XXX-XX.firebaseapp.com/)... I need to work from another computer... but can't understand how to repair this... Seems I will need to reinstall windows (Mac on same computer does fine).

Comment: UPS... in my case it was the antivirus, not even deactivating it resolved the issue, I needed to deinstall it... sighs! Well... I think I'm puting it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same issue, and after trying all the options on [this post](http://www.techinpost.com/fixed-error-err_connection_reset-code-problem), and checking the ones from your post, I finally decided to try one more option...

**Deinstalling or adjusting the antivirus** (Eset nod32 was my case), and it WORKED!

After reinstalling I traced the antivirus SSL filtering blocks --- without asking, so in this antivirus you need to specify the filtering to be interactive (asks you upon filtering).

I believe the problems comes from the certificate of FirebaseApp.com, that it may not be including ANY subdomain (which is how our apps work). If that's not the case, then the problem could be from ESET by not having firebaseapp.com in some SSL trust whitelist, or maybe it determines the SSL certificate has some other issues or isn't verifiable with TRCA.